# Microsoft word as an attachment to Lotus notes email using WORD VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a protected word document, which has some text fields and plain text. I created a command button in this to attach this word document as an attachment in the Lotus Notes. That works fine, but now I want the specific email address in the To Address of the lotus notes.

My code is

```
Sub emailcoord()

  Options.SendMailAttach = True
  ActiveDocument.SendMail
  Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show "abc_xyz@gmail.com"

End Sub
```

I am calling this sub from buttonclick.

Can anyone please help me how to add "To address" to the lotus notes.

Answer (score 0):

You can find much information here : http://www.fabalou.com/VBandVBA/lotusnotesmail.asp

and on this SO thread : [Sending formatted Lotus Notes rich text email from Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686384/sending-formatted-lotus-notes-rich-text-email-from-excel-vba)

Regards,

Max