# Java Agent generating file link

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus, javaagents

In [lotus](/questions/tagged/lotus) manually you need to create a hotspot link if you want to send a reference to a file on a network drive.
Is it possible to send an e-mail programatically by Java agent with the same link?

(In [lotusscript](/questions/tagged/lotusscript) mimeentity [can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686384/sending-formatted-lotus-notes-rich-text-email-from-excel-vba) for this purpose, but I am not sure.)

Comment: so you want to create a java agent in a Notes database which send emails with a clickable link to a file stored on a network drive?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jake Howlett created a nice Java Class for sending HTML E-Mails which you can find here: 
http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/BLOG-20100108-0129
This can be used to generate a HTML link to the file.

Otherwise you can use the RichTextItem class and write a file:// link . Notes Mail will display this a s aclickable hotspot link.

This is a modified sample code (originally from from the notes help) which works on my machine:

```
import lotus.domino.*;
import java.util.Vector;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {
public void NotesMain() {
    try {      Session session = getSession();
    AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
    // (Your code goes here) 
    Database db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();
    Document doc = db.createDocument();
    Item subject = doc.replaceItemValue("Subject","Rich text item");
    RichTextItem body = doc.createRichTextItem("Body");
    body.appendText("Link:");
    body.addNewLine(2);
    body.appendText("file://c:\\temp"); //ENTER PATH TO LINK TO HERE
    // Save the document
    doc.save(true, true);
    doc.send("ENTER YOUR MAIL ADDRESS HERE");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}}
```

In my original post I had a mistake with escaping the \ of the path (you must use \)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought something similar to this. However body.AppendText("file://c:\temp"); does not create a real link, it is just a simple text. Or there is some Notes client setting to display it as a link?

Comment: Did you send the email and opened it in your mail file?

Comment: Yes, I have tested the code. The mail sent by the agent contains a simple text instead of the link.

Comment: I updated the sample code above - I tested this code and it works on my computer with a Notes 8 mail file.